# Finding the total quantity of each ingredient

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_orders (
      "order_id" INT,
      "customer_id" INTEGER,
      "pizza_id" INTEGER,
      "exclusions" VARCHAR(4),
      "extras" VARCHAR(4),
      "order_time" DATETIME
    );
    INSERT INTO customer_orders
      ("order_id", "customer_id", "pizza_id", "exclusions", "extras", "order_time")
    VALUES
      ('1', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 18:05:02'),
      ('2', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 19:00:52'),
      ('3', '102', '1', '', '', '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
      ('3', '102', '2', '', NULL, '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
      ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('4', '103', '2', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('5', '104', '1', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:00:29'),
      ('6', '101', '2', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-08 21:03:13'),
      ('7', '105', '2', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:20:29'),
      ('8', '102', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-09 23:54:33'),
      ('9', '103', '1', '4', '1, 5', '2020-01-10 11:22:59'),
      ('10', '104', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-11 18:34:49'),
      ('10', '104', '1', '2, 6', '1, 4', '2020-01-11 18:34:49');
    
    
    CREATE TABLE pizza_toppings (
      "topping_id" INTEGER,
      "topping_name" VARCHAR(50)
    );
    INSERT INTO pizza_toppings
      ("topping_id", "topping_name")
    VALUES
      (1, 'Bacon'),
      (2, 'BBQ Sauce'),
      (3, 'Beef'),
      (4, 'Cheese'),
      (5, 'Chicken'),
      (6, 'Mushrooms'),
      (7, 'Onions'),
      (8, 'Pepperoni'),
      (9, 'Peppers'),
      (10, 'Salami'),
      (11, 'Tomatoes'),
      (12, 'Tomato Sauce')

CREATE TABLE pizza_recipes (
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,
  "toppings" VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO pizza_recipes
  ("pizza_id", "toppings")
VALUES
  (1, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10'),
  (2, '4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12');
```

and I'm asked: **What is the total quantity of each ingredient used in all delivered pizzas sorted by most frequent first?**

I did this, but I don't know why it shows me values where there shouldn't be (like in order 1 shows me exclusions 2 and 6 from order 10)

```
select  order_id, extras_split, toppings_split, exclusions_split
from
        (SELECT value as extras_split, order_id, pizza_id 
        FROM customer_orders 
        cross apply string_split(extras, ','))as a
        JOIN (
        SELECT value as toppings_split, pizza_id
        FROM pizza_recipes cross apply string_split(toppings, ',')) as b
        ON a.pizza_id = b.pizza_id
        JOIN (
        SELECT value as exclusions_split, pizza_id
        FROM customer_orders 
        cross apply string_split(exclusions, ',')) as c
        ON b.pizza_id = c.pizza_id
group by  order_id, extras_split, toppings_split, exclusions_split
order by order_id
```

So I would need some help figuring that out, and from there how to add the counts of pr.Toppings + co.extras and then subtract the co.Exclusions and add the names from the pizza_toppings table, which I was guessing maybe a cte with the final result an join the cte with the pizza_toppings.toppings_id to get the names, but I'm not sure about that last part.

Expected final result would look a bit like this:

| Ingredient | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| cheese | 15 |
| Bacon | 10 |
| Beef | 8 |

Comment: Being a beginner, I would strongly recommend getting out of the habbit of storing delimited data as soon as you can; you should have rows in a joining table thus avoiding the complication and performance impact of then having to split your delimited data into those rows every time you query it.

Comment: yeah im taking notes hehe thanks

Comment: also any weird thing in the tables, I was given those tables It wasnt me btw

Comment: The question does have a problem - with "toppings" being non-atomic.  If a column is not atomic then it's a violation of 1NF (First Normal Form).  If you are a beginner then you may have learned about 1NF and "Normalization".  A violation of normalization in a beginner's class is a major problem IMO.  The only reason to include such a question that violates 1NF is the person teaching the class is an idiot who didn't understand normalization.  I would not learn database basics from an idiot, and take a different class from someone that is smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final result looks strange. I mean numbers. They do not support your input data or maybe I calculated it incorrectly. But anyway, the code below should work or give you an idea how to achieve what you were asked. The first step is to calculate toppings - exclusions, then add extras and the final step is count frequency followed by sorting.

```
with pizza_ingredients as (
            select order_id, pr.pizza_id, ltrim(rtrim([value])) as topping 
            from customer_orders co
            inner join pizza_recipes pr on pr.pizza_id = co.pizza_id
            cross apply string_split(toppings, ',')
            where ltrim(rtrim([value])) not in (select ltrim(rtrim([value])) from string_split(exclusions, ','))
            union all
            select order_id, pizza_id, ltrim(rtrim([value])) as topping 
            from customer_orders co
            cross apply string_split(extras, ',') 
            where isnull(extras,'') <> ''
)
select topping_name, count(topping) as quantity 
from pizza_ingredients
inner join pizza_toppings on topping_id = topping
group by topping_name
order by 2 DESC
```

[image]

Comment: I made it similiar way ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dV4SymLA)), except using `except` for exclusions and got exactly same results,, so confirmed.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Ill sit down and study all this! I was doing it the other way around, I wanted to first calculate the extras plus the normal toppings of the recipes, then take out the exclusions hehe thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query

```sql
SELECT
  pt.topping_id,
  pt.topping_name,
  COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM customer_orders co
JOIN pizza_recipes pr ON pr.pizza_id = co.pizza_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(TRIM(t.value) AS int) AS topping_id
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(pr.toppings, ',') t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(TRIM(t.value) AS int)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(co.extras, ',') t
) t
JOIN pizza_toppings pt ON pt.topping_id = t.topping_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(co.exclusions, ',') ex
    WHERE CAST(TRIM(ex.value) AS int) = t.topping_id
)
GROUP BY
  pt.topping_id,
  pt.topping_name
ORDER BY
  quantity DESC;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sb5w62IR)

Note that your tables are badly denormalized. Ideally, `pizza_recipes.toppings` and `exclusions` and `extras` would be in separate junction tables. For example you could do the following query

```sql
SELECT
  pt.topping_id,
  pt.topping_name,
  COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM customer_orders co
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT rt.topping_id
    FROM recipe_topping rt
    WHERE rt.recipe_id = co.pizza_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.topping_id
    FROM recipe_topping rt
    WHERE rt.recipe_id = co.extras_recipe
) t
JOIN pizza_toppings pt ON pt.topping_id = t.topping_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM recipe_topping rt
    WHERE rt.recipe_id = co.exclusions_recipe
)
GROUP BY
  pt.topping_id,
  pt.topping_name
ORDER BY
  quantity DESC;
```

Comment: Yeah I think Ill keep studing and then look for another place for practice cases. Everyone always tells me that something is off about the tables hehe Thank you for the help.